# VBA: List of RecordSource in Form

Tags: vba, ms-access-2007

I want to scan to all RecordSource in my ADP Forms. One of my Form might call in the wrong View. It usually sets in RecordSource Property. The problem is there are about 300+ forms in my ADP. So I want to print all RecordSource in each form in able to find and correct the problem. Here are what I did so far.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

Dim sForm As String

Dim obj As AccessObject, dbs As Object
Set dbs = Application.CurrentProject

Dim cCount As Long
cCount = 0

For Each obj In dbs.AllForms

        ' Print name of obj.
        sForm = "Form_" & obj.name

            Debug.Print cCount  & "  " & Forms(sForm)!RecordSource

        cCount = cCount + 1

Next obj

End Sub
```

The error is Access can't find Form. Run-Time Error '2450'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps:

```
For Each obj In dbs.AllForms
    DoCmd.OpenForm obj.Name, acDesign
    Set frm = Forms(obj.Name)
    Debug.Print cCount & "  " & frm.RecordSource

    cCount = cCount + 1
    DoCmd.Close acForm, obj.Name, acSaveNo
Next obj
```